# how can i avoid the ddos of my own websocket server

Tags: reactjs, websocket, webrtc, ddos

hello in my application I use Web Socket and WebRTC. With Web Socket I establish a connection between the users. I try to connect as many users as possible, but the Web Socket seems to be overloaded. I think because of all the offers and answers webSocket is overloaded. Does anyone know what to do ?

Is there a WebSocket from Meteor or another architecture to support the server ?